# Using Python to animate a property of an addon

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I am using a Python script to create a number of text objects in Blender, and would like to have them use the [Typewriter script](https://github.com/boombatower/blender-typewriter-addon) so that they appear to be typing themselves out as the animation progresses. Here is my script so far:

```
import bpy, random

words = ['MANY', 'WORDS']
font = bpy.data.fonts.load('(path to font)')
mat = bpy.data.materials.get("Blue") 

for n in range(len(words)):
    new_x = (random.random()*3.2)-1.6
    new_y = (random.random()*15)-10.5
    new_z = (random.random()*1.8)-0.9
    new_scale = (random.random()*0.125)+0.125
    new_time = round(random.random()*300)
    bpy.ops.object.text_add(location=(new_x, new_y, new_z), rotation=(1.5708, 0, 0))
    new_text = bpy.context.object
    new_text.scale = (new_scale, new_scale, new_scale)
    new_text.data.font = font
    new_text.data.align = 'CENTER'
    new_text.data.body = words[n-1]
    new_text.data.materials.append(mat)
```

To realise this, I would change the `new_text.data.body` to `new_text.data.source_text` and insert two keyframes for `character_count` - one at `new_time` with value 0, and one at `new_time+60` with value of `len(words[n-1])`. However, when I run the following commands in the console:

```
>>> ob = bpy.context.object
>>> ob.keyframe_insert(data_path='character_count')
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: bpy_struct.keyframe_insert() property "character_count" not found
```

This is the data path I get when right-clicking on the field and selected "Copy Data Path", so I am reasonably sure that I have the right name. Can anyone advise me how I might resolve this? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character_count property is on the data part of the text object.  The Font panel is the data part for a text object, just as it is the mesh for a mesh object, armature for an armature object etc.

With a text object selected and in the console.

```
>>> C.object.data.keyframe_insert("character_count")
True
```